# Switch model according to user

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-views

I need to switch model according to user, in my wiews.
I have 2 ideas.

**1) First idea**

I have a model, I call it Cakes (maaany properties). It's abstract.

```
class Cakes(models.Model):
    radius = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I extend it 2 times: Vegan Cakes - Non vegan Cakes

```
class VeganCakes(Cakes):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'vegancakes'
class NonVeganCakes(Cakes):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'nonvegancakes'
```

Im my views I do something like:

```
from cakes.models import *
# Cakes
# VeganCakes
# NonVeganCakes
```

A standard view could be:

```
class CakesView(DetailView):
    template_name = "desserts/cake_view.html"
    model = Cakes
    context_object_name = 'Cake'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CakesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

I'll like to switch the CakesView's "model" field according to the user.

Sasha, is in a nonvegan group.
Jessie, is in a vegan group.

**so in the view, the model becomes: Cakes > > VeganCakes/NonVeganCakes**

**2) Second idea**
Otherwise I'll like to do it before the views:

```
#if currentUser is Vegan
from cakes.models import Cakes as VeganCakes

#if currentUser is nonVegan
from cakes.models import Cakes as NonVeganCakes
```

I'm using this approach to separate the contents because I need to hide many data according to users/groups. The data would never be used together (vegan-nonvegan) and never need to interact.

A different approach/advice will still be very appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to override the `get_queryset` method of your views. Here are the [default implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/views/generic/detail.py#L58) and here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset).

```
class CakesView(DetailView):
    template_name = "desserts/cake_view.html"
    model = Cakes
    context_object_name = 'Cake'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CakesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        model_class = None
        if is_vegan:
            model_class = VeganCakes
        else:
            model_class = NonVeganCakes
        return model_class.objects.all()
```